# how to save static content in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm a little confused about how to configure docker to save user generated files in a volume. I have my docker-compose set up as such:

```
services:
  web_service:
    container_name: webapp
    build: .
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./wwwroot/static
        target: /usr/lib/volumes

    ports:
      - "5000"
    networks:
      - webnet

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: mynginx:1.0
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
    driver: bridge
```

Every time I run `docker-compose up` it creates a new volume. I want to be able to reuse a volume and save the static files across containers and on top of that I have a sqlite database file in the working directory that needs r/w permissions. I guess what I don't really understand is the difference between source and target, because I assume the source is the file storage folder, but the documentation uses a named volume as the source.

I've read through the documentation and it shows this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mydata
        target: /data
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./static
        target: /opt/app/static

networks:
  webnet:

volumes:
  mydata:
```

Comment: Why do you think it creates a new volume every time?  I'd expect the syntax you show to work, and to save files on the host in the named directory.

Comment: I forgot to point out that I prune the containers before I rebuild the image `$sudo docker container prune`.